# I get an error sed: 1: "1~2d": invalid command code ~ when I use sed '1~2d' sample.txt

Tags: terminal, command-line, unix

On macOS version 11.2.2.

```
$ which sed
/usr/bin/sed
```

sed version: 4.8 SED(1)

When I run this code on Ubuntu, it works.

```
$ sed '1~2d' sample.txt
two
four
six
```

But when I run this on macOS, both in zsh and bash, it won't work.

```
$ sed '1~2d' sample.txt
sed: 1: "1~2d": invalid command code ~
```

Why doesn't it work on macOS?

How can I make it work?

[Update]
When I run man sed | grep GNU, it outputs telling that This is a GNU extension.

[image]

Comment: What is the result of `sed -V`, of `type sed`, of `ls -l $(type -p sed)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An adress like `1~2` is a GNU extension, it's not available in the BSD `sed` which is part of macOS.

The probably easiest way out of this is to install GNU `sed` with

```
brew install gnu-sed
```

and then run `gsed '1~2d' sample.txt`.

If you don't want to install additional software see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560411/how-to-remove-every-other-line-with-sed for alternative approaches.

Comment: When I see `which sed` the output is /usr/bin/sed and the last line of man sed is sed 4.8 SED(1). Isn't it GNU sed?

Comment: @shin macOS doesn't come with GNU sed in `/usr/bin`. I assume that, one way or the other, the man page of GNU sed is somewhere in your `MANPATH`.